# HtmlUnit getPage() throwing exception

Tags: java, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

The `getPage()` function of HtmlUnit is throwing `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Invalid TLS padding data` and `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac` not always but when after two three requests it starts throwing exception.

The URL uses `HTTPS` protocol.

Any idea what can be wrong with it? How can be resolved?

SNIPPET:

Calling the webpage for multiple request throws above exceptions:

```
public static WebClient getLoggedInHtmlUnit() {


        webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false); // I think this speeds the thing up
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);



        try {

            final HtmlPage page =  webClient.getPage(LOGIN_URL); //https://consyn.elsevier.com/user/login

            final HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);  

            final HtmlTextInput textField =  form.getInputByName(USERNAME_BYINPUT_NAME);
            final HtmlPasswordInput pwd =  form.getInputByName(PASSWORD_BYINPUT_NAME);        
            textField.setValueAttribute(USERNAME);
            pwd.setValueAttribute(PASSWORD);   

            final HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputsByValue(LOGIN_BYVALUE).get(0);
            button.click();

            return webClient;

        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }



}
```

Comment: Does the error occurred only on a single url or any? Can you give a small pice of code showing your problem?

Comment: No, on different URLs.. see edit for snippet.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318729/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-bad-record-mac

Comment: this worked like a charm! 


http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following and it worked fine and prints "Page Loaded ..." . Use this **inside the Try catch block** **not outside**. I have tried in Ubuntu Linux environment with jdk 6. If this fails check with another OS other than MAC. (I think you are using a MAC)

```
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
            HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)     webClient.getPage("https://consyn.elsevier.com/user/login");
            System.out.println("Page Loaded ...");
```