# Setting SSL version with FileUtils.copyURLToFile

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am using FileUtils.copyURLToFile to copy a url into a local file. The URL is using https. It worked perfectly fine until they changed the SSL version.

Is there a way to specify the SSL version with the apache commons.io? eg something like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573192/how-do-i-set-ssl-protocol-version-in-java-and-how-do-i-know-which-one-javax-ne) but allowing me to keep using FileUtils.copyURLToFile.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can use HttpsURLConnection to open connection, set SSL version and then use FileUtils.copyURLToFile:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

context.init(null, null, null);

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

FileUtils.copyURLToFile(connection.getURL(), file);
```